# How to access function parameter of function parameter?

Tags: scala

For below sum method :

```
  def sum(term: (Int) => Int , next: (Int) => Int) : Int = {
        0
  }
```

How can I access the Int parameter of function `term`

If I try :

```
  def sum(term: (param : Int) => Int , next: (Int) => Int) : Int = {
        0
  }
```

I receive error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - only classes can have declared but undefined members - not found: type param - 
 ')' expected but ':' found.
```

Comment: I think the short answer is: You don't and it does not make sense. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`term: (Int) => Int` simply tells the compiler that you are passing in a function that takes a a `Int` parameter and returns another `Int`, there's no need to bind the variable:

```
scala> def sum(term: (Int) => Int) : Int = {
 |       term(10)
 |     }
sum: (term: Int => Int)Int

scala> def useSum() = {
 |       sum {
 |         someInt =>
 |           someInt + 1
 |       }
 |     }
useSum: ()Int

scala> useSum
res6: Int = 11
```

You could also curry the `sum` function and pass in the parameter you want to apply to the function you are passing:

```
def sum(someInt: Int)(term: (Int) => Int) : Int = {
  term(someInt)
}

def useSum(someInt: Int) = {
  sum(someInt) {
    someInt =>
      someInt + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as when `sum` is applied, passed `term` function is not yet called. BTW there is a syntax error in the second code, as parameters of lambda can't be named in this way.